# How to create and store a plot for each iteration of a Do loop

Tags: plotting, functions

I have created the following code below. Its purpose is for me to divide the plot into grids and for each grid I reterive the center point's co-ordinates.

```
dp = DensityPlot[(E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + 
         y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Minimal", PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
ClearAll[centers2]
centers2[region_ : Disk[{0, 0}, 1]][{nc_, nr_}, {xrange_, yrange_}] :=
  Select[RegionMember[region]]@centers[{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]
{xrange, yrange} = {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}};

{nc, nr} = {10, 10};


Show[dp, Graphics[{White, PointSize[Medium], Circle[], 
   Point@centers2[][{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]}]]
means[n_] := MovingAverage[Subdivide[##, n] & @@ #, 2]; &;



 

cp = centers2[][{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]
```

Next I have made a Do loop that will perform calcualtions to get a variable called angle. This code is given below.

```
Do[point = Part[cp, i]; x = Part[point, 1]; y = Part[point, 2]; 
 ex = (E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2)^2; 
 ey = ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2;
 s1 = ex^2 - ey^2;
 s2 = 2 ex ey Cos[0];
 inside = 2 s2/s1;
 angle = ArcTan[inside], {i, Length[cp]}]
```

Now what I would like to have a command inside the Do loop that I can use to plot an ellipse based on the variable angle (this will be used to give the angle that the semi major axis makes with the x axis) for very iteration of the Do loop. There is a constant semi and minor axis. The point the ellipse will have to be centered at is the point that is currently being used in the Do loop.

I am not sure how to do this inside the loop for all the iterations, however I have a found a method to plot an ellipse given as

```
ellipsoid[center_, {majorradius_, minorradius_}, angle_] := 
 GeometricTransformation[
  Ellipsoid[center, {majorradius, minorradius}], 
  RotationTransform[angle, center]]
ad = Pi/3;
sd = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick}], Opacity[.75], Transparent, 
   ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.1}, ad], Opacity[1], Red, Point[{0, 0}],}]
Plot[3, sd, {x, -10, -10}]
```

I also would like to store these plots as I would like to then combine all of these ellipse plots onto the densityplot I have made in the beginning

All help is much appreciated

Comment: Use `Table` instead of `Do`, then you get a list of results back. If you then return the appropriate `ellipsoid[...]` expression from each iteration, you can simply wrap `Graphics` around the list you got from `Table` to create your plot.

Comment: @LukasLang what do you mean by wrapping `Graphics`

Comment: What `Plot[3, sd, {x, -10, -10}]` means in your code?